# Animated infinite scrolling with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, infinite

I'm making an animated infinite scrollview and I've used the [StreetScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from Apple. I'm adding an animation with NSTimer (1 second interval) invoking a 1 second animation where I'm setting the content offset (for 40 pixels or so) of the scrollview. It works perfectly but the problem occurs when the method `recenterIfNecessary` is called which basically resets the `contentOffset` of the scrollview but that's also animated so it appears like the scrollview is "unwinding" back to the center and then resumes animating.
I'm guessing I should cancel the animations when I'm recentering but I'm not sure how.

Code which is invoked with NSTimer:

```
- (void)performScroll {
    CGFloat currentOffset = self.horizontal ? self.contentOffset.x : self.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat newOffset = currentOffset + self.kActualPixelsPerSecond;
    CGPoint offsetPoint;
    if (self.horizontal)
        offsetPoint = CGPointMake(newOffset, 0.0);
    else
        offsetPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, newOffset);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kScrollingTimeInterval
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                                [self setContentOffset:offsetPoint animated:NO];
                     } completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Try calling recenterIfNecessary in performScroll and not in layoutSubviews

Comment: Tried but the same thing happens. I've also tried it in the completion block but the thing is the animation is never really finished because the timer duration and animation duration are the same. If i don't put it in the `if (finished)` block, it also unwinds back to the center.
I can get it to work almost perfectly if I set the animation duration 0.01 seconds less than the `NSTimer`'s interval but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late. I was also encountered the same situation when I tried to build an infinite scroll view.

The solution I found was that:

1. To make a flag that indicates if the scroll view is under programmatic scroll, and check that flag each recenter. If that flag is on, the recenter should be discarded.
2. Use CADisplayLink to implement scroll programmatically. You might make your own timing function here if you want animation curves more than linear.
3. At the end of each programmatic scroll, call recenter additionally.